# Cluster behavior on worker crash

Tags: node.js

I'm using cluster to fork workers that process files received over http/express. I'm currently testing the recovery when processing a file that makes the worker crash (I detect the crash with `on('exit',...` and re-fork a new worker).

I'm witnessing a strange behavior: in the case of a poisoned file that would make a worker crash, my logs show that all workers receive the file and crash (whereas normally, only a single worker would process a non-poisoned file). And on the client-side, it shows that the HTTP request has only been sent once. Any reason that would explain that odd behavior?

EDIT: code extract

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
        worker.on('message', function(filename) { 
            console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' processing ' + filename);
        });
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
        worker.on('message', function(filename) { 
            console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' processing ' + filename);
        });
    }
} else {
    var app = express();
    app.use('/', express.static('public'));
    app.use(multer({ inMemory: true }));

    app.post('/detect', function(req, res) {
        var image = req.files.image;
        if (!image) {
            res.status(400).send({ error: 'missing image' });
            return;
        }

        process.send(image.originalname);

        // some code that may crash
    });

    var server = app.listen(nconf.get('port'), "0.0.0.0", function () {
        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Cluster API is unstable so there is some issues, you cant use it in production. https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: It has been unstable for years, and _is_ being used in production by a lot of people. Without more context (actual code), it's anyone's guess what may be causing the described behaviour.

Comment: @robertklep I've added some code extract, thanks!

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues. Running your code and simulating a random crash in a worker only exits that particular worker and not the others, although I obviously cannot test your `process.send()`. What perhaps could be worth a try is disabling `inMemory` on multer, although I don't have a specific reason to think that it may be causing your problems (since we're dealing with separate processes).

Comment: Tried disabled `inMemory` in multer but still the same odd behavior... Not sure if it's related, but I also notice sometimes that the process.pid traced by the worker is different from the one traced by the master!